# itunes stating internet connection is lost even when my internet connectoin is available

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I submitted to the apple store multiple times but today I found one problem regarding the internet connection.
While validating the application shows the internet connection is lost. Whereas I have checked my internet connection it's working fine. Is anybody facing the same issue?

Comment: I noticed Xcode is a bit of a pain lately when it comes to submitting apps, especially in my office which has caused my app submission to keep dropping out. Somehow, Apple's Application Loader to submit app seems to work though, you might want to try using that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be on Apple's end, not on your end.  If you know the hostname or IP address of the server you're submitting to, you could try pinging it, however Apple has many servers - the hostname may not be clear from iTunes' UI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. It was IP blocking by the organization